# Collect info about selected elements to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this kind of markup:

```
<span class="makearray">click me</span>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="noindex"><span class="txt">blahblah</span></li>
        <li class="noindex"><span class="txt">blahblah</span></li>
        <li class="index"><span class="txt">text1</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="index"><span class="txt">text2</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="noindex"><span class="txt">blahblah</span></li>
                        <li class="index"><span class="txt">text3</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click `.makearray` element, I want to collect info about all my `.txt` elements that are **first-children** of `.index` list-items (maybe using Jquery `.index()` method?) and make this array:

```
var info = [{
    "index": "1",
    "txtcontent": "text1"
}, {
    "index": "2",
    "txtcontent": "text2"
}, {
    "index": "3",
    "txtcontent": "text3"
}]
```

where `index` property is an integer indicating the position of `.index > .txt:first-child` element within `.container` element, and `txtcontent` is the result of Jquery `text()` method applied to this element.
Note: `txt` elements may have `contenteditable` attribute, I even may insert new `li.index` elements into `ul` dynamically, so every time I click `.makearray`, the existing array must be replaced by the new one (that is, rebuilt from scratch).

Please, help, thank you

Comment: That's great. Write some code.

Comment: I did not include the code because it was easy to collect the info, but I was not able to split this into separate objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [child combinator `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) to target the spans, and jQuery's [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to build the array:

```
var arr = $('.index > .txt').map(function(i,el){
    return {
        index : i,
        txtcontent : el.textContent
    };
});
console.log(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39VyA/1/

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. But I hope he'd be able to figure that out alone.

Comment: Yes, `li > .txt` must be replaced by something like `.container .index > .txt:first-child`. And by the way, my properties **must** be JSON-like: `"index": i+""` (I've heard there's a difference between unquoted and quoted properties).

Comment: @lyricallywicked JSON is a string, my code is giving you a js array. If you want JSON, just `JSON.stringify(arr)`.

Comment: I meant all properties of all objects must be **quoted**

Comment: @lyricallywicked That doesn't make any difference when dealing with js (at least not with property names like those). But you can add the quotes if you want. In any case, if you want json you need to convert with the method i showed in the previous comment.